# Javascript tail recursion instead of loop

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion

In one of Douglas Crockford speeches, He favours the use of tail recursion over loops. this code was presented,

```
function repeat(myFunc) {
  if (myFunc !== undefined) {
    return repeat(myFunc);
  }
}
```

I thought to define a myFunc but don't know if a static counter can retain its state during function calls or use a global counter. but being new to javascript I wanted to ask first. How can this be used in an example, say to count down from 10 to 0? Thanks.

Comment: where does the countdown happen?

Comment: `function repeat(myFunc, cnt) {
  cnt = cnt || 0;
  if (myFunc !== undefined && cnt !== 10) {
    return repeat(myFunc, ++cnt);
  }
}`

Comment: i think your browser is stuck while doing this the function is never stopped

Comment: The role of myFunc is irrelavant in the code you have given, either it is undefined from the start, and the function doesn't get called recursively, or it is not, and it runs indefinitely. I don't think Crockford would have presented this code. Maybe you forgot brackets somewhere? I mean: myFunc has to be called at some point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function `myFunc` somewhere -- and evaluate the result for further call of `repeat`.

```js
function repeat(myFunc) {
    if (myFunc()) {
        repeat(myFunc);
    }
}

var count = 10;

repeat(function () {
    document.write(count + '<br>');
    count--;
    return count >= 0;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can this be used in an example, say to count down from 10 to 0?

Pass a `Number` to `repeat`, call `repeat` with decremented number as parameter until variable parameter is equal to `0`

```js
function repeat(n) {
  console.log(n)
  if (n) {
    return repeat(--n);
  }
}

repeat(10)
```

Comment: The name myFunc is a bit misleading in this case :)

Comment: @trincot Yes. Tried to change original `js` at OP  at little as possible. `myFunc` could be any varible; updated variable name to `n`

Comment: @guest271314 your solution does not print zero at the end. not withstanding this, the reason for the question is to understand how to call a function and the number count down was 'just a use case. Poor one I must add.

Comment: @FredJ. _"your solution does not print zero at the end."_ ? Logs `0` at `console` here. Yes, a function could be called to decrement number passed as parameter, though not necessary to achieve expected results. `-`  operator provides same results as calling a function to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that keeps state without global variable:

```js
function repeat(myFunc, arg) {
    if ((arg = myFunc(arg)) !== undefined) {
        repeat(myFunc, arg);
    }
}

repeat(function (count) {
    document.write(count + ',');
    count--;
    if (count >= 0) return count;
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what approach you want, but you can use this to count down recursively

```
function repeat(myFunc, times) {
  if(times > 0 && typeof myFunc == 'function') {
    myFunc(times);
    repeat(myFunc, times-1);
  }
}
repeat(alert, 10);
```